# Oracle get ID after insert into table with trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table INV_SRV_ATT with trigger:

```
create trigger TRG_INV_SRV_ATT_PK
    before insert
    on INV_SRV_ATT
    for each row
begin
  select SEQ_INV_SRV_ATT.nextval into :new.ID from dual;
end;

/
```

So, ID is increased for each new insert.

In stored procedure I have insert like this:

```
insert into INV_SRV_ATT (format_id, name, service_id, ACCOUNT_ID,
                                                   inserted, inserted_by, DEF_VALUE_VARCHAR,
                                                   DEF_VALUE_NUMERIC, DEF_VALUE_DATE, DEF_VALUE_DECIMAL,
                                                   SYS_ATT, name2, VERSION_ID)
                          (select format_id,
                                 name,
                                 services.service_id,
                                 -1,
                                 sysdate,
                                 P_AUTH_USER_ID,
                                 DEF_VALUE_VARCHAR,
                                 DEF_VALUE_NUMERIC,
                                 DEF_VALUE_DATE,
                                 DEF_VALUE_DECIMAL,
                                 SYS_ATT,
                                 name2,
                                 VERSION_ID
                          from inv_srv_att
                          where id = attributes.SRV_ATT_ID);
```

How to get ID from that insert?